# Multiple ASP.net MVC2 applications on IIS7 ( hosting an MVC app. in another MVC app. )

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-2, iis-7, asp.net-mvc-routing

What I am trying is the following:

1. I got an MVC app. running DIRECTLY in "Default Web Site"...
2. I got another app. ( ProductionService ) which is another standalone app..

Looks like this in IIS-Manager:

[image]

My problem is, that a requets to "ProductionService" is not routed to the app., but instead is handled by the MVC-app. running under "Default Web Site"

I tried the MVC IngoreRoute method, but it didn't change the result.. here is my last "RegisterRoutes" with all my try & errors ;)

```
        routes.IgnoreRoute("Staging/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("ProductionService/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("StagingService/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("/Staging/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("/ProductionService/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("/StagingService/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("~/Staging/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("~/ProductionService/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("~/StagingService/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("~/Staging/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("~/ProductionService/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{*Staging*}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{*ProductionService*}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{*StagingService*}");
```

So, any ideas what I can do? Maybe configure sth. in IIS directly?

Comment: Where are the rest of the routes? Like the one that is registered (not ignored) by default

Comment: removed that in the post only... the rest is the default routing which is set during project creation in visual studio... but that doesn't matter anyway, because the top-application is working fine (except for the routing to the sub.application )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it... the web.config is somehow inherited to the sub.applications, so if i do a construct like this in the sub-app., for my case it was solved:

```
    <!-- This is required if you want to run with sub-applications in IIS as it inherits the web.config somehow...-->
<membership>
  <providers>
    <clear/>
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager enabled="false">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <clear/>
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```